# iosでスプラッシュ画面の後に真っ白な画面になる

Tags: ios, cordova

ionic3で開発しているのですが、platform.readyが発火していないようなのです。
android用にビルドしたものは問題ありませんでした。

環境
ionic info

```
cli packages: (/Users/sample/node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0 

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.9
    Cordova Platforms  : ios 4.5.4
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:

    ios-deploy : 1.9.2 
    ios-sim    : 6.1.2 
    Node       : v6.9.5
    npm        : 6.1.0 
    OS         : macOS High Sierra
    Xcode      : Xcode 9.4.1 Build version 9F2000 

Environment Variables:

    ANDROID_HOME : not set

Misc:

    backend : pro
```

使用プラグイン一覧

```
branch-cordova-sdk 2.6.24 "branch-cordova-sdk"
code-push 2.0.5 "CodePushAcquisition"
cordova-android-support-gradle-release 1.4.4 "cordova-android-support-gradle-release"
cordova-base64-to-gallery 4.1.3 "base64ToGallery"
cordova-plugin-app-version 0.1.9 "AppVersion"
cordova-plugin-badge 0.8.7 "Badge"
cordova-plugin-browsertab 0.2.0 "cordova-plugin-browsertab"
cordova-plugin-camera 4.0.3 "Camera"
cordova-plugin-code-push 1.11.11 "CodePush"
cordova-plugin-compat 1.2.0 "Compat"
cordova-plugin-console 1.1.0 "Console"
cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview 2.4.0 "Crosswalk WebView Engine"
cordova-plugin-device 2.0.2 "Device"
cordova-plugin-dialogs 2.0.1 "Notification"
cordova-plugin-file 6.0.1 "File"
cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.7.1 "File Transfer"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 3.0.0 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.2 "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard"
cordova-plugin-network-information 2.0.1 "Network Information"
cordova-plugin-safariviewcontroller 1.5.4 "SafariViewController"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 5.0.2 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.2 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.3 "Whitelist"
cordova-plugin-zip 3.1.0 "cordova-plugin-zip"
phonegap-plugin-push 2.2.3 "PushPlugin"
```

試したこと
・--prodオプションのビルド
・index.htmlにContent-Security-Policyヘッダーを追加
・ionic cordova platform rm ios 後に、ionic cordova platform add ios
・全プラグインをrm後にadd
・cordovaのバージョンを8から7.1に変更

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/136659

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboardが原因のようでした。
ionic-plugin-keyboardのページで、このプラグインは廃止予定のためcordova-plugin-ionic-keyboardを推奨していたので変更したのですが、当面はionic-plugin-keyboardを使用し続けることにします。